# Proving that the sum $\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n} (-1)^{w^Tx}$ is either $2^n$ or zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, summation, finite-fields

Please help me prove that $$\sum_{x \in \mathbb{F}_2^n} (-1)^{w^T \cdot x} = 2^n \delta(w)$$ for any vector $w \in \mathbb{F}_{2}^n$ where $\delta(w) = 1$ for $w = 0$ and $\delta(w) = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: There is no $w$ on the LHS.  Is this the name of something standard?

Comment: I cannot transform all the formula correctly; so you see what is W from the link in the post. Thanks

Comment: W means weight..

Comment: muzzlator, thanks for the edit..

Comment: No problems.  Welcome to Math.SE, hope you see how to apply my solution.  If not, consider it an exercise to show that for any set of size $n$, there is a bijection between the subsets of odd size and the subsets of even size.

Comment: Thanks. Can you please give more details. I mean, can you show using the notation?

Answer (score 2):

For $w = 0$, it's clear that the sum just counts elements of the vector space and so you have $2^n$

If $w \neq 0$, take the support of $w$ and show that there are exactly the same number of subsets with odd size and with even size.  Use these to cancel everything else out.

Comment: +1 A standard alternative argument with this type of sums is the following. If $\neq0$ there exists a $y\in V$ such that $y$ and $w$ have a single common one, i.e. $(-1)^{w^T\cdot y}=-1.$ Fix such a $y$. Then $x$ ranges over the vector space as $x+y$ so ranges, so the asked sum $S$ satisfies
$$S=\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{w\cdot x}=\sum_{x+y\in V}(-1)^{w\cdot(x+y)}=\sum_{x\in V}(-1)^{w\cdot(x+y)}=(-1)^{w\cdot y}S=-S,$$ hence $S=0$.

Comment: Wow, that's nice.  Thanks @JyrkiLahtonen

Answer (score 1):

Imagine how
$$\begin{align*}\sum_{x\in\Bbb F_2^n} (-1)^{w^T \cdot x}
&=\sum_{x_1\in\Bbb F_2}\sum_{x_1\in\Bbb F_2}\cdots\sum_{x_n\in\Bbb F_2}(-1)^{w_1x_1+\cdots+w_nx_n}\\
&=\left(\sum_{x_1\in\Bbb F_2}(-1)^{w_1x_1}\right)\cdots\left(\sum_{x_n\in\Bbb F_2}(-1)^{w_nx_n}\right)
\end{align*}$$
which is $2^n$ if all $w_k=0$ and $0$ if at least one $w_k\neq0$.